# Send multiple params into log4net

Tags: log4net

I'm trying to send arbitrary arguments into log4net at runtime.  Is it possible to define parameters on the fly and send them in?  I know you can define global params like this:

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["MyColumn"] = "MyValue";
```

but I'm thinking more along the lines of:

```
myArrayOfCoolStuff["IP"] = "127.0.0.1";
myArrayOfCoolStuff["UserName"] = "jbleaux";
log.Error(myArrayOfCoolStuff);
```

Given how log4net tends to fail silently when you give it garbage, I'm hoping to find expertise instead of just trying it.  Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-6-Log-Event-Context.aspx) and in particular the part "Calculated Context Values". You could create a class that accepts your parameters and writes them in whatever format you need.

Comment: Neato.  Is there a risk in an asp.net situation of having 1 request set the threadContext and another request use it?  I'm worried about logging Alice's error with Bob's IP or something.

Comment: This would certainly be a problem if you leave information in the thread context for "longer" periods of time. You could however store the information in the session and access the session when "writing" the (global) context property.

Comment: I ended up doing this in an extension method and just putting a lock(log){} around the log object and it seems to work.  That is a performance hit, but this code only gets called for exception handling, so the performance hit on lock is the least of our worries.  Thanks.